# Store an int for every date in Java

Tags: java, calendar

Is there anyway for each date in a Calendar class to store an integer? So for example the 5th of June could store the number 5.

I would like this functionality since I am writing a booking system for a room and each reservation request has a different Id number. So I would like a calendar object to store the id number on each day.

Comment: Could you explain why you need this ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please consider adding more detail to your question so we have a better idea of what you're trying to do and how to implement it.  A code example would be great.  Of course it's possible, but without more detail it's hard to provide any working examples to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I hope there would be better way to organize your entity relations.
If you have multiple booking requests in a day, it doesn't make sense to add all those booking Ids to the date. Rather, In every booking, have a field called `requestedDate` and store the requested on Date. When you need all the requests made on a single date, you could filter it using this field.

for your current need, you could sub class `GregorianCalendar` class and add this variable `bookingId` with getters and setters.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class BookingCalendar extends GregorianCalendar {

    private Integer bookingId;

    public Integer getBookingId() {
        return bookingId;
    }

    public void setBookingId(Integer bookingId) {
        this.bookingId = bookingId;
    }
}
```

To test this:

```
public class CheckCal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BookingCalendar cal = new BookingCalendar();
        System.out.println(cal.getTime()); //Mon Mar 28 06:30:24 IST 2016
        cal.setBookingId(25);
        System.out.println(cal.getBookingId()); //25
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to store extra information in a `java.util.Calendar` object unless you implement your own subclass of (say) `GregorianCalendar`.

If we can infer from your example that the number you want to store is the "day of the month", then you don't need to store it.

```
  int dayOfTheMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_THE_MONTH);
```

Otherwise, you should represent a association between dates and numbers using a `Map`.  It would be better to use an immutable date type as the key; e.g.

```
  Map<LocalDate, Integer> dateNumbers = new TreeMap<>();
```

(If you used `Calendar` as the key type and some code called the `set` operation to change a key, the map's invariants would be invalidated.)

Alternatively if your "calendar" is equivalent to an array of dates, then you can make it an array of object that have a date field and a number field.  For example:

```
  public class Booking {
      private Room room;
      private LocalDate date;
      private int id;
      // constructor, getters
  }

  public class Bookings {
      // data structures representing all bookings, possibly
      // with maps for fast lookups.

      // methods for looking up bookings by id, date, room
      // methods for adding / removing / updating bookings
      // methods finding free rooms for a given day or day range
  }
```